# How do I configure a Contour heatmap to display colors for small overall data?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

Is there any way to configure a **heatmap** to have lower thresholds for high-density colors?

*Example*: I don't have too many data points for each geographic location, so as a result they're not showing up at all or are showing up in a very light color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a cleaner way of doing this but:

1. Create a new column where the value is always `100`. This can be done by using the Column Editor to make a column of all `1`s via 1[some numeric variable]/[some numeric variable]1, then another new column equal to that column * 100
2. Heatmap on the `sum` of that column rather than on the `count` of
   the rows.